# How can I re-size an image stored as a byte array and having a byte array with a resized copy of that image?

Tags: c#, arrays, winrt-xaml, image-resizing, tile

I have a byte array which corresponds to an image.
Now I need to re-size this image and store the re-sized image also as a byte array.

I've been trying A LOT of solutions that I found when researching, but NONE of them helped as they are all working with other images format or they don't result in a byte array or in any type that I could convert to a byte array.

It's driving me crazy as I'm not used to work with images and this confusing methods =/

I'm developing in C# a Windows Store App. I'll really appreciate any help! =)

Comment: Load your byte array to an image, resize it and save to MemoryStream. That is all.

Comment: L.B, how would you convert a BitmapImage to a MemoryStream on a Windows Store App? I can't find a way to do it, and I've been researching for a long time with no success =/